# On sabbatical vs on hiatus

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given  that *sabbatical* and *hiatus* may refer to a period of time taken from one’s main activity,

if I say that my professor is “on sabbatical” is it the same as if say that my professor is “on hiatus”?

Do they mean the same or are there different nuances or implications.

I couldn’t come to a clear conclusion looking up  the definitions given  online.

Answer (score 4):

In academic contexts, *sabbatical* is a semi-technical term with a very definite meaning: it is a period during which an academic is absolved of teaching duties in order to concentrate on research. It is **not** 'a period of time taken from one’s main activity', as both teaching and research are parts of the job of an academic. A sabbatical has to be approved by the institution that the academic works for, and the approval process normally requires that the academic specify the nature of the research for which the sabbatical will be used. A period of time that an academic takes off in order to attend to private matters would not be referred to as a sabbatical in academic contexts.

Outside such contexts, the meaning of the term is not very precise, and it may be used loosely for a limited break in one's regular work (but longer than an ordinary vacation), taken in order to pursue personal enrichment.

*Hiatus* simply means a break in something; it carries no implications as to the purpose of the break.

If an academic is actually on a sabbatical, it would border on insulting to refer to it as a hiatus, break, or time off, as it would suggest that the academic is not doing the work for which the sabbatical was approved.

Answer (score 0):

***On sabbatical*** means that your professor will eventually return to the same job. It traditionally lasts one year and it can sometimes be paid.

> A sabbatical is an extended period of time off of work that is ***mutually agreed with your employer*** above and beyond your annual leave entitlement. (*[The sabbatical guide uk](https://thesabbaticalguide.com/sabbatical-leave-uk/)*)

***On hiatus***, however, means that he has taken a break from work in general, not sure how long, and it is not sure that he will return to the same employer. He might start a new job.

Comment: Not sure “on hiatus” does imply you are not coming back. And I know of people who never came back from their sabbaticals.

Comment: That is a matter of choice. A sabbatical ensures you can keep the same job _if you want to_. It's taking leave from work with the option to come back. While  _hiatus_ is a more general term. Like a hypernym of _sabbatical_. It's a career break.

Comment: Actually, that is a matter of institution-specific rules: at many places there is, in fact, a contractual obligation to come back and teach for a period of time after a sabbatical. Incidentally, a sabbatical should not be confused with an unpaid leave, taken in order to accept a visiting appointment at another institution (paid for by that other institution); somebody's never coming back happens more often in the cases of the latter kind.